# Select All Of One Value and Another by Condition with Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these documents :

```
{
    "people" : [
        {
            "Gender" : "Male",
            "Age" : 31
        },
        {
            "Gender" : "Female",
            "Age" : 22
        }
    ]
}
{
    "people" : [
        {
            "Gender" : "Male",
            "Age" : 31
        },
        {
            "Gender" : "Female",
            "Age" : 24
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "people" : [ 
        { 
            "Gender" : "Male",
            "Age" : 31
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all the documents where **IF** there is a **woman**, then this woman must be **22**. So it must return all Male gender regardless of the age and all Female gender where age = 22:

```
{
    "people" : [
        {
            "Gender" : "Male",
            "Age" : 31
        },
        {
            "Gender" : "Female",
            "Age" : 22
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "people" : [ 
        { 
            "Gender" : "Male",
            "Age" : 31
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You basically need an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition where one of the options negates `"Female"` from being a gender in any array element and the other condition only matches those which also have the age constraint using [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    { 
      "people.Gender": { "$eq": "Male", "$ne": "Female" }
    },
    {
      "people": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Gender": "Female",
          "Age": 22
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Which returns your two documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b06898bfb4739ed7db59c18"),
        "people" : [
                {
                        "Gender" : "Male",
                        "Age" : 31
                },
                {
                        "Gender" : "Female",
                        "Age" : 22
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b06898bfb4739ed7db59c1a"),
        "people" : [
                {
                        "Gender" : "Male",
                        "Age" : 31
                }
        ]
}
```

Using `"people.Gender"` as a path for all values on the array we can test for `"Male"` with [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) and `"Female"` with [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) to mean there is "only" a male present.

The [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) then allows the "alternate" constraint that IF the array element has a `"Female"` then their age must be `22`. So you only get those with "just a male" and "joined with" results where the Female also met the age constraint in the element.